# Kubernetes on OpenStack

Tags: kubernetes, openstack

We have a private OpenStack infrastructure. We want to create a Kubernetes infra on top of OpenStack. I want to use whatever block storage device we have in OpenStack as a HA storage cluster which can tolerate failures and is highly available as well.

I gather that I can use Glusterfs and achieve this. Is there any other opensource solution available? Any tips? any gotchas?

Answer (score 1):

A quick glance at the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) will show that Kubernetes supports using OpenStack Cinder for storage, as well as many other provisioners.

Comment: Yes but then cinder is not distributed. Its a local storage. I need replication and HA both.

Comment: It depends on what you're using as the cinder backend. We have great experience with Ceph.